# Kendo UI Scheduler refresh AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, refresh

What will be the refresh comment for kendo UI  scheduler in AngularJS. I can see in JQuery it works like the following code

```
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
scheduler.refresh();
```

What will be in AngularJS ?

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but if you give a name to the kendo-widget-name attribute (in this case "kendo-scheduler") like this:

```
<div kendo-scheduler="myScheduler"></div>
```

You can then refer to in the controller and call the refresh function:

```
$scope.myScheduler;
$scope.myScheduler.refresh();
```

If you're using a tag directive and so don't have a "kendo-scheduler" attribute to set, you can use the "k-scope-field" attribute instead.

You can read about it in the docs here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#widget-references